# притяжательные местоименные moй/moя/moё/moи

Tags: перевод, грамматика

Здравствуйте,

I need your help with this. I am learning this.

How to respond to: "как ваше имя?"

имя is средний род. Would that mean that I can respond with: Moё имя: Дженни?

Спасибо большое

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to respond to: "как ваше имя?"

You can either answer as you proposed, "**моё** имя Дженни" (which would be a full answer), or you could provide a short answer, "Дженни".

It is not a common question, however.  The more common would be

> Как Вас зовут?

to which you respond using the same form, "**меня** зовут Дженни".

Comment: 9 seconds between our similar answers )))

Comment: I have answered with меня зовут but I wanted to run this by you to make sure. I will award the point to Mr Bazonov since he was first as soon as the time window opens. Спасибо большое

Comment: Generally speaking you *could* answer "меня зовут..." when asked "как Ваше имя?" because those are pretty much interchangeable and serve the same purpose.

Comment: yeah, that was my guess. Спасибо большое

Answer (score 2):

You can hardly meet such a phrase "**Как ваше имя?**", it is rarely used in modern Russian. Rather, it would be "**Как вас зовут?**" and you can answer "**Меня зовут Дженни.**"

Talking about the possessive adjectives and pronouns, yes, with **имя** we use **моё**, neuter gender.